# How does the Day/Night cycle work on the Elemental Plane of Fire?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, planes, time

So I found out, that there is a curfew every night in the City of Brass on the Elemental Plane of Fire. This makes me wonder: How does a day/night cycle work on the Elemental Plane of Fire?
Is there a sun and if so, does it rise and set like a normal sun?

I'm looking for information in any sourcebook of whatever edition of Dungeons & Dragons.

The source for the curfew is the book "Secrets of the Lamp" for 2nd edition published 1993. From page 27:

> [...] a strict curfew is enforced each night

Comment: might be tangential to the question, but where did you find out that the City of Brass has a nightly curfew? Just there's a curfew in the city as depicted in, for example, Critical Role, doesn't mean it's canon. (It might be canon, I don't know - that's why I'm interested in the source)

Comment: @PixelMaster Found it in the Wiki for Forgotten Realms. https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/City_of_Brass#Law_.26_Order
They credit the book "Secrets of the Lamp" if I see that correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The sun is brightening and darkening

I have researched material from editions before 5th and found nothing... until the 5th-edition *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 55) tells us this about the [Elemental Plane of Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#PlaneofFire):

> A blazing sun hangs at the zenith of a golden sky above the Plane of Fire, waxing and waning on a 24-hour cycle. It ranges from white hot at noon to deep red at midnight, so the darkest hours of the plane display a deep red twilight. At noon, the light is nearly blinding. Most business in the City of Brass (see below) takes place during the darker hours.

Before 5th edition, there was no mention of a sun, with the only book that implied a day/night cycle in the City of Brass being *Secrets of the Lamp*.

Comment: "Most business in the City of Brass ... takes place during the darker hours."  Which rather contradicts the strict curfew.

Comment: @Tektotherriggen That's correct. I think 2nd and 5th edition take place during different ages, so the curfews could have been lifted in favor of interplanar traders? Or the authors just didn't care.